How do we restrict multiple uploads using the presigned url
I am writing a cdk app to generate a upload presigned url.
I want the presigned url to be used by the client for one upload. Once the upload is complete the url must be invalidated.
I do have a expiry time set in my presigned url but this doesn't guarantee the upload has happened once.

I did refer to some posts and there were 2 suggestions.

Once a file is uploaded, have Lambda move the file to /uploads/image to /received/image or something similar. (Not a preferred solution for me)
Invalidate the access key by Lambda and the presigned url will be invalidated.
Use the temporary credentials from param store.

Can someone explain with cdk code how the solution 2 or 3 works?

You could create a presigned URL with the precondition of IfNoneMatch = '*', then in the upload specify the accompanying If-None-Match header.  This will prevent a duplicate upload, and some point after the presigned URL has expired, you can remove the object.

There is no default mechanism to allow that. Presigned URL manages expiry by datetime. You have to use custom solution with a Lambda function to manage the lifecycle of the presigned url.
As you have already read about few different ways we can achieve that, with 2 you can consider:

creating a Lambda function that generates the presigned URL
stores it in DynamoDB
another Lambda function that invalidates the URL after the upload is complete

so your CDK will include (I won't give all those in detailed code, you should be able to create those with cdk modules easily.
You can refer to some documentations like here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda-readme.html

a Lambda function that generates the presigned URL and stores it in DynamoDB (bear in mind that the Lambda function should have read/write permissions to the DynamoDB table + generate presigned URLs for the S3 bucket)
another Lambda function that invalidates the presigned URL after the upload is complete (the Lambda should also have access with read/write permissions to the DynamoDB table)
and create an S3 notification to trigger the invalidate function on object creation


How do we invalidate the presigned url that’s stored in dynamo db? Do you have a code example?

by invalidating the presigned url it doesn't really mean there's an invalidating (at least as of now at time of reply) because there's no feature right now that's supporting that. e.g. you can modify the permissions of the S3 object associated with the presigned URL. By changing the object's ACL (Access Control List) or bucket policy to deny access, you effectively invalidate any presigned URLs that were previously issued for that object. This method does not require altering the URL itself but ensures that access is denied

or move / rename the object in S3, any existing presigned URLs will become invalid since they point to a non-existent location. This is a straightforward way to ensure that old URLs cannot be used

more complicated but supported by service handlign the token/nonce is AWS Lambda authorizer that checks against a list of valid nonces or tokens stored in DynamoDB or another database. If a request comes in with an invalid or previously used nonce, deny access even if the presigned URL is still technically valid. This adds an additional layer of control over how URLs are accessed. you can also implement your own code mechanism to do that

for revoking access u can try using s3 client that leverages this https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/put_object_acl.html
something like s3.put_object_acl(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key, ACL='private')
print(f"Access revoked for {object_key} in bucket {bucket_name}.")
